# R: Loop over a list of data.frames to generate successive set of coordinates

Tags: r, loops, 3d, dataframe, coordinates

**EDIT:** Sorry, I did not see that the post did get cropped when I was fighting with tables layout.
To sum up the issue, I was wondering what was the best (and most efficient) way to script an **iterative computation**?

The general idea, which may not be clear enough in the following example, is in fact pretty straight forward.

I have a list of tables *(M.Motion)* filled with coordinates *(M)*, and vectors. Each vector is the distance between Mn and Mn-1.

I have a table *(SalOrigine)*, which is a picture converted as a table with every pair of coordinates for every pixel in the picture (288*162). Each set of *(M)* coordinates is the center of one picture projected in 3D space.

My objective is to **compute the position of every pixel for each picture** from the *(M.Motion)* list, using the motion vector and the coordinates of each *(M)*.
The first picture always has the same starting position in space, and the following pictures have a sequential fashion.
To do so, I was thinking **to compute the first *(SalOrigine)* table, and then to launch an iterative loop from it in order to generate Sal(n) tables with the new coordinates**. Each *Sal(n)* is using the previous *Sal(n-1)* set of coordinates in conjunction with the data from *(M.Motion)*.

And I was not able to get a working script in R !

**EDIT END/**

Here is the situation :

- I have a list with a few hundreds data frames of one row. M(x,y,z) is a dot and dM(x,y,z) is the vector from dot(n) to dot(n+1). Basically, each dot is the center of a plane, and the vector is the distance between two of those planes.

  ```
  >head(M.Motion)

  $`1`
  M.X   M.Y   ID  t      M.Z     M.dX M.dY M.dZ M.Yfov
  1     1     1   0.014  1       0    0    0    954.85

  $`2`
  M.X   M.Y   ID  t      M.Z     M.dX M.dY M.dZ M.Yfov
  2.5   2.5   2   0.016  2.5     1.5  1.5  1.5    954.88

  etc.
  ```
- I have also a "blank" data frame I will be using to start the loop. It is the list of the center of every pixel in a plane of 288x162 pixels on (x,y).

  ```
  >head(SalOrigine)

  ID S.X  S.Y S.Z
  1  0.5  0   0.5
  2  1.5  0   0.5
  3  2.5  0   0.5

  etc.
  ```
- I want to create a script that generate a new data.frame with a new set of coordinates for each frame of M.Motion.
  Meaning, starting from SalOrigine:

-S.X2 = (S.X + M.Motion$1$M.X + M.Motion$1$M.dX -144.5) # -144.5 is used to correct the position of S.X2 because M.X is the center of the picture

-S.Y2 = (S.Y + M.Motion$1$M.Y + M.Motion$1$M.dY)

-S.Z2 = (S.Z + M.Motion$1$M.Z + M.Motion$1$M.dZ -81.5) #same as -144.5

Then I will have

```
    >head(Sal1) fake values

    ID S.X  S.Y S.Z  M.dX M.dY M.dZ S.X2   S.Y2  S.Z2
    1  0.5  0   0.5  2    3    5    485.5  85.5  45.5
    2  1.5  0   0.5  2    3    5    486.5  86.5  46.5
    3  2.5  0   0.5  2    3    5    487.5  87.5  47.5

    etc.
```

From here the idea is to compute each Sal(n) from the coordinates of Sal(n-1), with the addition of the relevant dot M(x,y,z) and vector dM(x,y,z) so that :

-Sal2$S.X2 = (Sal1$S.X2 +  M.Motion$2$M.X + M.Motion$2$M.dX -144.5)

- The project behind this mess is summarized in this image :

http://tof.canardpc.com/view/297db212-3bd5-457d-b949-5099a1027ad0.jpg

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I had trouble with the formating yesterday, I hope the edited part makes more sens.

Comment: I think you problem is overcomplicated because you're trying to use `M.dX` and `M.dY` in your solution instead of using absolute coordinates

Comment: Also, it seems that SalOrigine contains not one but all pictures. How do you know which picture from `SalOrigine` belongs to which record in `M.motion`?

Comment: But, there is no way around the vector part if I want to compute the updated position of each pixels of a picture. Keep in mind that the coordinates in SalOrigine and Sal(n) represent a 2D plane that I have to project in a 3D space. I agree it's quite complicated, but so far I am not aware of any other alternative to achieve this goal.

Comment: SalOrigine contains only one picture, I converted the matrix into a table with the center of each pixel (1 pixel = 1 unit). You have a big table with a list of every pairwise coordinates of the picture.

Comment: Where did `S.Z` column in `SalOrigine` come from then?

Comment: From the translation of the plane into 3D space. The original set of coordinates is (x,y) in a 2D space, but since the plane will always be perpendicular to (x,y) in 3D space, as shown in the picture, the y axis become the z axis.

Comment: Why don't you replace `S.X2 = (S.X + M.Motion$1$M.X + M.Motion$1$M.dX -144.5)` by  `S.X2 = (S.X + M.Motion$2$M.X - 144.5)`, which should be identical to your expression since `M.Motion$1$M.X + M.Motion$1$M.dX` is equal to `M.Motion$2$M.X`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand what your looking for either, it seems like you don't have an issue around how to approach any particular part.
That being said I took a stab at what I think your looking for.

```
    library(data.table)

for(l in M.Motion){ #making a dataframe out of the list
  if(!exists('dfmotion')) dfmotion  <- l
  else dfmotion <- rbind(dfmotion, l)
}

#setting it data.table
dfmotion  <- as.data.table(dfmotion)
SalOrigine  <- as.data.table(SalOrigine)

#setting merge keys
setkey(dfmotion, ID)
setkey(SalOrigine, ID)

#combining sal & motion
combined  <- SalOrigine[dfmotion]

#doing the requested row based operations
combined[, ':=' (S.X2 = (S.X + M.X + M.dX -144.5),
                 S.Y2 = (S.Y + M.Y + M.dY),
                 S.Z2 = (S.Z + M.Z + M.dZ -81.5))]
combined[, S.X2 := S.X2 + M.X + M.dX)] #-144.5 already in S.X2?
```

Make sure to remove dfmotion prior to rerunning this code as the loop will break(or worse not break) if you rerun and dfmotion already exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even if my first post was kind of a mess to be honest. I tried to script this by myself all day, but my R skill was not good enough. I will try to adapt your code, but I already see a problem with the ID merging. The ID from the two tables are not the same, because the ones from SalOrigine will be used later to grab color data for each row.

Comment: No reason you cant create another column with a workable key and then use that to merge back in. See the substr & nchar functions for a likely approach to this. Try to adjust your code based on the template above and then edit your post with your progress and well work through it.